# Firefox table css generate tbody killing table width

Tags: html, css, firefox, width, css-tables

I am working on taking an IE only site and making it cross browser. Everything is looking  good in IE, Chrome, and Safari. However Firefox isn't happy.

I have a table class called "datatable" it is as the name suggests a datatable. I am trying to get it to stretch to 100% of width of the div it's contained in. The div above is 100%. When I use firebug to check it, the table is stretching to 100%. However, the tbody that Firefox generated is not stretching to 100%. So because of that the rows in the table are as small as the tbody. So I have no idea how to fix this. I tried 
`tbody{width:100%;}` and it did nothing.

Any ideas I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Can you psot also a bit of html and css?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Okay I just answered my question... inside the css there was a generic css like this...

```
table
{
    border:0px solid #000000;
    padding:0 0 0 0;
    border-collapse:collapse;
    border-spacing:0;
    display:block;
}
```

I removed the display:block and everything works great now... I had looked for that on the table.datatable definition, but did think to look for a generic one in the file...

Answer (score 1):

This might be silly, but make sure you're selecting the tbody correctly

```
#datatable tbody{width:100%}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, 
solved it eventually by setting the width property of the header cells (i figured that's what firefox looks at to decide the tbody width).

table.table_class th { width: 115px; }

it's an option if, like me, you don't want to mess with generic css.

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if you have `font-size` set to something lesser than `100%`.

Answer (score 0):

If some browsers need `display:block` in `<table>` so ...

```
table {
    // Something..
    display: block;
}
body:not(:-moz-handler-blocked) table {
    display: table;
}
```

**Example case :** HTML in e-mails

*Just a bit hack if you still need to preview on Firefox*